# OnDragListener not working for DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have a class which extends DialogFragment. I have to get current coordinates of the dialogue just after the drag. So I implemented OnDragListener to the class and override the onDrag() method. But I didn't get any call to onDrag() method.

If it is not possible, is there any way to get current coordinates of DialogFragment in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onSaveInstanceState()` method in your `DialogFragment` like following:

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putFloat(WINDOW_X, getView().getX());
        outState.putFloat(WINDOW_Y, getView().getY());
    }
```